# Scheduled tasks in Django to update data in the models (database)

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, pythonanywhere

I need to schedule tasks via Pythonanywhere, to update some records in my database.
As an example, I do have Events as models:

**models.py**

```
class Events(models.Model):
    event_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    event_info = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    event_date = models.DateField(default=now)
    event_time = models.TimeField(default='00:00')
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    event_status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=EVENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default='New Event')
```

Also within that Events class in models.py I have the following:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if date.today() > self.event_date:
            self.event_status = 'Completed Event'
        super(Events, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks to that, all events in the past, change their status to Completed. Problem is, you need to refresh the page to have the `save` function run on the production website.
It also drives some other functions, e.g. showing the user the count of active events - this one as well, in order to show the right active number of events, has to be refreshed manually.

By scheduling tasks in PA to run overnight, iterating through all Events, and if in the past, changing their status.

I created the below file and uploaded it to PA Tasks.

**tasks.py**

```
from .models import Events
from datetime import date

def verify_events():
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    for event in all_events:
        if event.event_date < date.today():
            event.event_status = 'Completed Event'
            event.save()
```

I got an error from PA when the task run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxx/XXXXXXX/xxxxxx/tasks.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .models import Events
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

2022-10-24 23:30:30 -- Completed task, took 14.35 seconds, return code was 1.
```

Looks like **tasks.py** could not read it from the database (->import from Models)
What's the best way to set up PA tasks to run and write to the database?

**EDIT**
This is indeed an issue with the working directory while on PythonAnywhere.

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ScheduledTasks/

I did add the below to the **tasks.py** but still the same error (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named XXX`):

```
import os

path = "/home/myusername/myprojectname/mainfolder/"
os.chdir(path)
```

Folder structure - both tasks.py and models.py are in the same folder:
`myprojectname/mainfolder/tasks.py`
`myprojectname/mainfolder/models.py`

`__init__.py` is there.

Still not working.
So, while on PA, should I change some settings of the working directory? Or how to fix it, so I can import models (i.e. Events from db) and update using Tasks?

Answer (score 1):

`ImportError` has nothing to do with the database, it's a Python error raised on your line 1. Its description is pretty accurate: "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: ok, so in this case I should use absolute import? I will be testing this. `import app.models` then `from app import models` and `from app.models import mymodel`

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing your project structure. Here I would suggest to use the absolute import